# Wrong result of getting JSON in django rest

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

Trying to send this JSON:

```
{"delivery":{"delivery_time":"2016-05-31T12:18:47Z","delivery_adress":"123","phone":"123"},"paymentMethod":{"id":"1","title":"123124123"},"summ":"23","success":false}
```

To my serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    delivery = DeliverySerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)
    paymentMethod = PaymentsSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ( 'delivery', 'paymentMethod','summ','success') #'id',

    def create(self, validated_data):
        deliverys_data = validated_data.pop('delivery')
        delivery = Delivery.objects.create(**deliverys_data)
        paymentsMethod_data = validated_data.pop('paymentMethod')
        data=list(paymentsMethod_data.values())[:3]
        print(data)
        payment_method = Payments.objects.create(**paymentsMethod_data)
        order = Order.objects.create(delivery=delivery,paymentMethod=payment_method,**validated_data)
        return order
```

I need to get id and use it like primary key, but the result of print: [u'123124123'],

And I don't know where lost my id from JSON.

View

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def order_post(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Other serializers

```
class DeliverySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Delivery
        fields = ('delivery_time','delivery_adress','phone')#'id', 
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Delivery.objects.create(**validated_data)   


class PaymentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Payments
        fields = ('id','title') #
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Payments.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

But I must get id before it goes to PaymentSerializer.

Comment: What is your PaymentsSerializer ?

Comment: @electropoet added